# delphi oscillating progress bar

Tags: delphi, progress-bar, delphi-xe

I'm trying to create a oscillating progress bar on a form, ie. I'd like the progress bar to start at 0, move to complete and then return. Just like the lights used to on Kitt from Night Rider, or the new Windows 7 progress bars.

Does anybody know how to achieve this in Delphi XE.

Regards, Pieter.

Comment: The worst thing of this mode is that it falsely gives users the idea that they're looking at the actual progress; except that it restarts when it reaches the end (yeah it looks slightly different, that's not clear to everybody). Showing misleading information might be worse than not showing anything at all. If you want to show that the application is still busy and alive, I'd look for another way to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try a `TProgressBar` and set Style to `pbstMarquee`. Might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to XE so there is still a learning curve ahead!

Answer (score 2):

Theres a very nice progress bar (complete with source), styled on the Ubuntu progress bar, at http://jd-powered.net/notes/ubuntuprogress-delphi-component

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the Style to `pbstMarquee`. The other property to set is `MarqueeInterval` which controls the animation speed.

I don't believe it is possible with the plain Delphi progress bar to have the progress indicator move from left to right, and then return from right to left, like KITT!  Once it gets to the right it then starts again from the left.

Comment: Hassel.. err Heffernan: it's KITT :)

Comment: This one is close enough! Thanks you.